# Creating some objects from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a remote autosuggest with ajax and am having trouble making an ul with an onclick function. What I receive as the ajax response is simply something like

```
One Name
Another Name
```

separated by \n

so below is what I have so far. The problems it has: it's very ugly code, AND the line between /////////////// doesn't work. Apparently it saves a reference to the variable, and all elements fill the text input with the value of the last element.

Can anyone help me fix this? either a way to just pass a copy of the string to that function definition, or a hint, link, or whatever to the right way to do this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.suggestable').live('keyup', ( function() { suggest(this); } ));

    function suggest(inputTextField)
    {
        var inputString = inputTextField.value;
        var lookFor = $(inputTextField).attr('data-lookfor');

        if(inputString.length == 0) {
//            $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
        } else {
            $.post(AjaxVars.url,
                {
                    action: 'suggest-submit',
                    queryString: ""+inputString+"",
                    lookFor: ""+lookFor+""
                },
                function(data)
                {
                    // Clear the target div in a very very ugly way
                    document.getElementById('suggestionsList').innerHTML = "";
                    var myul = document.createElement('ul');
                    data = data.split("\n");
                    for(var index in data)
                    {
                        elem = data[index];
                        if(elem.length > 0)
                        {
                            var myli = document.createElement('li');
                            myli.innerHTML = elem;
//////////////////////////////////////
                            myli.onclick=(function() { fill(inputTextField, elem); });
//////////////////////////////////////
                            myul.appendChild(myli);
                        }
                    }

                    document.getElementById('suggestionsList').appendChild(myul);
                });
            }
    }

    function fill(object, thisValue) {
        object.value = thisValue;
//        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 600);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response function only:

```
function(data){
    $('#suggestionList').innerHTML = '<ul><li>' + data.split('\n').join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';
}
```

and somewhere outside of all that, inside `function suggest(){`:

```
$('#suggestionList').delegate('li', 'click', function(){
    fill(inputTextField, $(this).val());
});
```

---

FYI the reason that line didn't work is that the value of elem changes... to show you what I mean, take the following example:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   $('#someDiv').bind('click', function(){ alert(i); });
}
```

that will show '10' no matter what div you click on because the i variable keeps incrementing to 10 and all the functions reference that one variable.  To make this work you need a closure of some sort:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   $('#someDiv').bind('click', (function(x){ return function(){ alert(x); } })(i));
}
```

now `i` is passed in to the inner function and referenced as x.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to clean it up, untested

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.suggestable').live('keyup', ( function() { suggest(this); } ));

    function suggest(inputTextField)
    {
        var inputString = inputTextField.value;
        var lookFor = $(inputTextField).attr('data-lookfor');

        if(inputString.length == 0) {
//            $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
        } else {
            $.post(AjaxVars.url,
                {
                    action: 'suggest-submit',
                    queryString: inputString,
                    lookFor: lookFor
                },
                function(data)
                {
                    $('#suggestionsList').html('');
                    var myul = document.createElement('ul');
                    $.each(data.split('\n'), function(k, v) {
                        if(v.length < 0)
                            return true;
                        (function(elem){
                            var myli = document.createElement('li');
                            myli.innerHTML = elem;
                            myli.onclick = function() { fill(inputTextField, elem); };
                            myul.appendChild(myli);
                        })(v);
                    });
                    $('#suggestionsList').appendChild(myul);
                });
            }
    }

    function fill(object, thisValue) {
        object.value = thisValue;
//        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 600);
    }
</script>
```